# In which process KPL sends DescribeStream request

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I'm using `KPL` for writing to Kinesis streams every 1 minutes .. actually i'm running a big process where i am sending `asynchronous` writing requests around `6400` records every minute ..

I've enabled `aggregiation` ..

However i'm receiving this error message randomly even when i try to brows the streams from the `AWS console`

```
Rate exceeded for stream xxxx under account xxx.
```

This error appears randomly with any stream not only the streams i'm writing to them.

So as per :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStream.html

My question is : In Which case `KPL` sends `DescribeStream` Requests ? Is in case of writing to the streams ? or no relation between them ?

Also is Streaming data from Kinesis by triggering Lambda function might be the reason ?